# Invisible Fence Wiring

Tags: wiring, electric-fence

Most of our backyard in fenced in and I would like to close off a section for the dog to run around with invisible fence. In the picture below the red is the existing fence. The blue line is where we'd like to run the invisible fence. The problem is getting the wire back to base station. So far I've come up with two mounting solution for the base station. Option A is in the basement and run straight out to the fence line. I'm not sure how to get the wire back to the base station with the option. Do I run a twisted pair back next to the original wire (pictured in purple)? Option 2 put the base station in my garage and I would run the wire along the fence line and then to the house (picture in green). Again I'm not sure how to get it back to the base station. The patio is pavers so I cannot go under them. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

[image]

Edit: Added single non-twisted purple
[image]

Comment: Be aware that the fence wire must leave the "base station" that's plugged into a power outlet somewhere, enclose an area of space that the dog is allowed to go into, then _return_ to the base station. Where the wire is twisted around itself (with the proper number of twists per foot), it won't zap the dog. Your green line would work just fine, you just have to decide where you want the base to be and completely enclose that area. Run the wire up high along the back of the house/garage to complete the loop, and it won't impact the dog - that's what we did with ours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad news is you need to make a closed figure with the "invisible fence" boundary

The good news is the boundary is allowed to have "useless" edges.

these edges will still be barriers to the dog, but the dog will never encounter them. so no problem.

[image]

There is some minimum distance you need to have between the edges, probably only a few feet. check the installation instructions.

Comment: It probably doesn't even have to be a few feet. I think you can run the wire out, loop it around a stick in the ground (just to hold it in place), then run it back right next to the outbound run and it'll still work just fine. It's only when it's twisted (at the minimum number of twists per inch/foot) that the signal gets cancelled out and doesn't zap the dog.

Comment: a parallel p[air is only slightly better at radiating than a twisted pair,  distance from the antenna to the receiver is in the order of 1 foot, so a similar separattion is probably needed for best performance.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop for the fence to work.

the ones I have used need a loop if the loop ends where the purple is and the wires are twisted from that point connecting to the station at the house,

yes it will work and the dog can walk over the twisted wires without getting the warning or a zap.

Make sure to read the instructions and be aware they make a Stubborn dog collar for the stronger willed dog that will try to keep going I have had to use those in the past but they do work with the proper settings and a loop.

Comment: Can I run a single non twisted wire from the house to the fence and loop back via a twisted pair along the purple? See edit in OP.

Comment: no, that''s not how twisted pairs work.